# layout elevation attribute doesn't apply in android studio design preview

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

Can someone explain why I cannot see the elevation effect in android studio design preview but I can see it only when I run the app?

Here are some pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell with such a short description. Did you try opening your project on another computer/operating system/graphic card/different Android Studio version? Did you try looking for your issue on Android Studio's issue tracker? Android Studio's preview has always had a good number of weird issues, so I wouldn't be surprised if your's was one of them.

Comment: @Zielony Do me a favor, can you just create a layout with a simple textView with let's say an elevation attribute of 8dp and tell me if you see any difference in your android studio design preview? 
Sorry but I have only one computer, so I can't test if it's a problem like you mentioned.
Let me know what are the results? Did the design preview changed?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just did what we discussed and I don't see any shadow. I'm using AS 3.1.3. See the code below. The button has some shadow, but it's not affected by elevation, so I suppose that it's just a part of its background's 9-patch or whatever. I don't see any current issues in the issue tracker.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=shadow%20design

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/carbon_white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@color/carbon_white"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:text="test"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@color/carbon_white"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:text="Button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: shadow test]

Comment: At least it's not a problem of my computer. Thank you for coming back and replying to my question. The only thing that I have to do now when I design layouts with elevation is to constantly run the app.